# Constrain grid rows to specified number

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Is it possible to force the grid to only render specified number of rows and ignore the rest of the items?
In the example code below I specify `repeat(3, 1fr)`, so I want to only render 3 rows no matter how many items it contains.
But this results in 4 rows:

```css
.grid-constrain {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.item-1 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item-2 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-constrain">
  <div class="item-1">TEST 1</div>
  <div class="item-2">TEST 2</div>
  <div class="item-1">TEST 3</div>
  <div class="item-2">TEST 4</div>
  <div class="item-1">TEST 5</div>
  <div class="item-2">TEST 6</div>
  <div class="item-1">TEST 7</div>
  <div class="item-2">TEST 8</div>
  <div class="item-1">TEST 9</div>
  <div class="item-2">TEST 10</div>
  <div class="item-1">TEST 11</div>
  <div class="item-2">TEST 12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting question... I don't think so. You may have to visually hide them, or use JS to remove them from the DOM. Would be interesting to see if it's possible with grid though..

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to force the grid to only render specified number of
>   rows and ignore the rest of the items?

No.

[**Grid Auto-placement | From MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Auto-placement_in_CSS_Grid_Layout)

> The CSS Grid Layout specification contains rules that control what happens
>   when you create a grid and do not place some or all of the child
>   items.
>
> If the grid does not have enough rows in the explicit grid to place all
>   of the items new implicit rows will be created.
>
> The default for automatically created rows in the implicit grid is for
>   them to be auto-sized. This means that they will contain the content
>   added to them without causing an overflow.
>
> You can however control the size of these rows with the property
>   grid-auto-rows.

If you are unable to alter the HTML, and are happy to visually hide this content, you could set `grid-auto-rows` to `height: 0`, and use the `overflow` property to hide content now *outside* the grid.

Use the following CSS:

```
.grid-constrain {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    /* added */
    grid-auto-rows: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/geNboO

```css
.grid-constrain {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(400px, 1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: 0px;
    background: grey;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-constrain">
    <div class="item-1">TEST 1</div>
    <div class="item-2">TEST 2</div>
    <div class="item-1">TEST 3</div>
    <div class="item-2">TEST 4</div>
    <div class="item-1">TEST 5</div>
    <div class="item-2">TEST 6</div>
    <div class="item-1">TEST 7</div>
    <div class="item-2">TEST 8</div>
    <div class="item-1">TEST 9</div>
    <div class="item-2">TEST 10</div>
    <div class="item-1">TEST 11</div>
    <div class="item-2">TEST 12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works in a lot of cases, but not, for example, if your content expands on hover.

Answer (score 1):

try using try using `.grid-constrain>div:nth-child(n+3)`

edit:

in you case, you can use:

```
@media (min-width: 601px) {
  .grid-constrain>div:nth-child(n+4){
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .grid-constrain>div:nth-child(n+2){
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: This selector will target all the items in the grid starting from the third item. I don't see how it can be used in OP's case.

Comment: oh sorry, use ``(n+4)`` instead and display:none;

Comment: The problem is, at different screen sizes a row will contain different numbers of items. This may work on a mobile, but on a laptop it won't.

Comment: ok i will update my answer to be more complete.

Comment: This worked for me -- I needed a solution that did not do overflow-y: hidden.